# A way to do news bar

Tags: c#, scrollbar

I need to do a news bar but I don't want to add another database query in the page which contains six queries, so I'm thinking about something like storing a one string param in txt file or maybe as a key in web.config and separate between each thread with a comma, and when I need to read these news I use the `split()` function to do the job.

Is this is a good practice or should I return to the usual DB query?

Comment: I can't accept an answer does not 'answer' my question .

Answer (score 1):

A query that fetches the news should not get too complex, so I would go for this instead of having to parse some arbitrary string.